# Gradle sync failed on Android studio after windows 10 update

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem.
After update my windows 10, gradle sync failed on android studio 3.0. I use gradle 4.5. Error message:

> The newly created daemon process has a different context than
>   expected. Java home is different. Expecting: 'C:\android-studio\jre'
>   but was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74'. Please configure the JDK
>   to match the expected one.

I run"studio64.exe". I try to add java.home to gradl.properties but it dosen't work. It's wierd because before update averythink was ok...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Android studio and JAVA_HOME environment
 variable refers to different directories. Check if these to values are same and they should refer to jdk path not jre.

Comment: In android studio it's File -> Project Structure -> JDK location?

Comment: @miosz is it refers to your jdk installation path?

Comment: yes, there I have a path: "C:\android-studio\jre" so I have to add this path to JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @miosz If this jre is a jdk installation yes. Try it anyway(you said it was working before) Also check this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-daemon-different-context/2146

Comment: I'm a bit confused... I add to JAVA_HOME location "C:\android-studio\jre" but it still doesn't work... :(

Comment: @miosz can you install jdk, and refer to it instead of C:\android-studio\jre in both places. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html